# give AWS IAM user ability to see screen shots

Tags: amazon-web-services

How do I give an AWS IAM user the ability to use the GetConsoleScreenshot action?

I came up with a policy that I think should do it:

```
 {
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "ec2:GetConsoleScreenshot",
                "ec2:DescribeImages",
                "ec2:DescribeInstances",
                "ec2:AvailabilityZone",
                "ec2:EbsOptimized",
                "ec2:InstanceProfile",
                "ec2:InstanceType",
                "ec2:PlacementGroup",
                "ec2:Region",
                "ec2:ResourceTag/tag-key",
                "ec2:RootDeviceType",
                "ec2:Tenancy"   
            ],
            "Resource": [
                "*"
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

I was using this as a reference: [Granting IAM Users Required Permissions for Amazon EC2 Resources](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/ec2-api-permissions.html)

What I'd like to know is if this is overkill to give someone the "ec2:GetConsoleScreenshot", ability? Are the other permissions implied by giving that one ability?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your IAM policy looks fine. It's not overkill to give a user the `ec2:GetConsoleScreenshot` permission, as this is required to to invoke [the `GetConsoleScreenshot` API](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_GetConsoleScreenshot.html). There are no other permissions implied by giving a user/role this permission. All actions in an IAM policy are atomic and do not imply allowing sub-actions.